# Base change matrix between Polar and Cartesian coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

R, Theta serve as a basis for 2 dimensional vector space, equally good as (0,1) and (1,0) do. But then, these two systems must be related by a base change matrix, where new basis is B.P where P is some invertible matrix and B, here being identity. 
But it seems i am lost. I can't find any such thing

Comment: $r, \theta$ are a *nonlinear coordinate system*, not a basis for a vector space. These are different things.

Comment: @lisyarus why they are non linear and why not a basis. At any single point ( atleast) you can write any vector in linear combination of them. Why are you saying so. Could you please elaborate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing. The relation between polar and Cartesian coordinates is not a linear transformation. The polar coordinate system's basis vectors are not basis vectors in the sense of a vector space - you can see that they are location-dependent.

Comment: Okey, it must preserve T(a+b)-->T(a)+T(b) alongside that scaler law to be called linear transformation?

Comment: [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity#In_mathematics)

Comment: @Wouter could you please elaborate as to why that is not a linear transformation. At any point you can write a vector in terms or the polar cordinates